# Extract text from a string in Jenkins groovy

Tags: regex, string, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I am not very good with string variables, especially in jenkins groovy, hence my question.

How can we in jenkins groovy extract a part of a string from some string variable using a found pattern?

For example, we have a string:

"The sun slowly descended below the horizon, casting vibrant hues of orange and {{ pink }} across the tranquil sea."

And we are guaranteed to know that there are {{ * }} in that line.

What is the simplest and easiest way to equate the * that is between the {{ }} to some variable?

I honestly don't even know how to approach this.

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
def line = "The sun slowly descended below the horizon, casting vibrant hues of orange and {{ pink }} across the tranquil sea."
def s = line.regex(.*{{.*}}.*)
def findColor = s[1]
```

?

Obviously it doesn't work, but I think it roughly outlines the end goal

This one will probably work:

```
def line = "The sun slowly descended below the horizon, casting vibrant hues of orange and {{ pink }} across the tranquil sea."
a = line.split("{{")
b = a[1] 
c = b.split("}}")
d = c[0]
```

But it's a terribly ugly solution and I'd like to know if it could be done concisely, beautifully, reliably and understandably all in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a regular expression:

```
def line = "The sun slowly descended below the horizon, casting vibrant hues of orange and {{ pink }} across the tranquil sea."
def color = (line =~ /\{\{ (.+) }}/)[0][1]

assert color == 'pink'
```

Comment: thanks, it works and still looks nicer